# Data Grid Column Labeling‏

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I have 48 columns in my datagrid, I want to label data grid columns header in such a way that every alternate column represent one hour while following column represent half hour i.e

if my first column is 00 then my next column should be 00:30 in this way 01 should be followed 01:30 and so on. I  have tried this, but I think I am messing up my nested loops.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i += 2)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name = Convert.ToString(i);
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j += 1) {
         dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name =  Convert.ToString(j) + ":30";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++) {
      dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText = (i/2).ToString("00") + (i% 2 == 0? ":00" : ":30");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I was using a smartphone for typing (horrible! )

Comment: @eren: the 2nd edit is not needed. It makes the answer better, but the OP could also use his brain... ;-)

Comment: @eren: now you can. ;-) but don't abuse it.

Comment: Thanks, i promise i won't (except this ''thank you' comment) ;)